# Chances to get a specific Image

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Do you know CS:GO coinflip sites?
I am trying to make a website with VS2017 and its a betting website just like coinflip. The user clicks a button and the coin(Image) will either be T or CT , they will win depending on what they chose.

I can do this with T.image || CT.image and it will be a 50% chance.

What I'm trying to do is that the user only has 20% chance of winning and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

P.S : I'm not really making a betting website to scam people's money. Its for a school project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a random number between 1 and 5.

If the number is 5, user wins. Else, user loses.